# Can anyone identify Xamarin Forms IOS intermittent crash with the following stack trace

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash, stack-trace

My company's Xamarin forms app is giving us a lot of HockeyApp reports about a crash in IOS that we cannot locally replicate. The managed trace is:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "[Unknown]"
File name: '[Unknown]'
System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(bool)
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream.Dispose(bool)
System.IO.Stream.Close()
System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Deserializer.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Xamarin.Forms.Application.d__74.MoveNext()
Xamarin.Forms.Application.d__51.MoveNext()
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate.d__8.MoveNext()
UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext.c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0()
Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply()
UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int, string[], intptr, intptr)(wrapper managed-to-native)
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], IntPtr, IntPtr)
UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[], string, string)
DM.iOS.Application.Main(string[] args) [This is our application's main method]
```

We are unable to replicate this issue locally. It is happening to a small percentage of our users. None of them have reached out to us, so we do not know whether it is happening on launch, or when they attempt to perform some action within the code.

This issue does not seem to come from any section of our own code, as the stack trace only references our Main function.

It does not seem to be isolated to any particular one of our builds, nor to any particular version of IOS. Our Hockeyapp error grid doesn't have any concentrations that we can see.

Does anyone have any advice on what this issue might be caused by, and how we might make it stop happening? It seems like a Stream is failing to dispose off of a xamarin deserializer, but I have no idea what the class in the fifth line might be, or why it is attempting to dispose of a stream.

-Thanks,
Walter Langendorf
DYMO Software